# asking account password when pull in bitbucket?

Tags: php, git, bash, bitbucket

I created git locally and commited my files, then  I am trying to pull my code to bitbucket in first time, I am getting error.

```
git remote add origin https://shihab-inf@bitbucket.org/shihab-inf/lsn.git
git push -u origin --all
```

remote repository successfully added but `pull` is not working. Git bash asking password and I put correct password,that time getting following error,

"remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you have an account password set in your account profile."

How can I fix?

Comment: Do you have any special character in your password?

Comment: no, I am using very simple password

Comment: What version of git are you using?

Comment: `git version 2.6.4.windows.1`

Comment: Double check if this is the right password by login to the bitbucket web site

Comment: do we need to enable ssh key or something like that?

Comment: ssh would not involve your http password, so that would be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If http access really does not work, you can try and switch to ssh:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:shihab-inf/lsn.git
```

Make sure to [configure your ssh keys first](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html).

Comment: ssh difficult for me